# Mysql query from ordered query

Tags: php, mysql

I've done some research and ended up with this query.

```
SET @row_num = 0;
SELECT
   @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_number
  ,id
  ,maxPoints
FROM users
ORDER BY maxPoints
```

...that gives me indexes of table ordered by maxPoints. And now comes the query for smarter people...

How do I get the row_number WHERE **id** = $i AND ... (other parameters) from this result.

Is it possible to do it by one composed query or do I need to split those queries on php side? I'm not able to put it up syntactically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put it in a subquery and select from that

```
select row_number
from
(
    SELECT id, @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_number
    FROM users
    CROSS JOIN (select @row_num := 0) r
    ORDER BY maxPoints
) tmp
where id = $id
```

BTW you can init the `@row_num` variable with a subquery too, like I did in my query

Comment: Piece of cake for you, huh? Thank you. Works like a charm. I'll be working on my skills.